# Align ragged right and ragged left in equation environment

Tags: equations, columns

I would like to write a financial calculation that is numbered as an equation. `tabular`, `split` and `align` do not seem to work. `tabular` delivers an error witin the `equation` environment.

The result should look like this:

```
Wood      10,000 €
Steel     25,000 €
Coal       5,000 €
Oil      100,000 €
------------------
Sum      140,000 €
```

That is, the right “column” is ragged right whereas the left “column” is ragged left.

This code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
            \text{Wood}\ \ & 10{,}000\ \euro\\
            \text{Steel}\ \ & 25{,}000\ \euro\\
            \text{Coal}\ \ & 5{,}000\ \euro\\
            \text{Oil}\ \ & 100{,}000\ \euro\\
            \hline
            \text{Sum}\ \ & 140{,}000\ \euro
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

delivers

[image]

.

A workaround, at least for the right “column”, could be to insert `\phantom{0}` or `\phantom{00}` in front of the shorter numbers. But the problem regarding the left “column” still remains.

Comment: That's a job for a `tabular`, rather than `split`.

Comment: @egreg: Using `tabular` within the `equation` environment results in an error. But what I actually need from the `equation` environment is its numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l r @{} }
Wood  &  10,000\,\euro\\
Steel &  25,000\,\euro\\
Coal  &   5,000\,\euro\\
Oil   & 100,000\,\euro\\
\hline
Sum   & 140,000\,\euro
\end{tabular}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a `\midrule` from `booktabs` look better than `\hline` here?

Comment: @daleif Most certainly; but the table should be refactored anyhow.