# Align centered, ragged right and ragged left in align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, amsmath

Writing

```
\begin{align*}
        && a &= b\\
        \Leftrightarrow&& b &= c\\
        \Leftrightarrow&& c + 2 &= 3 + 5\\
        \Leftrightarrow&& d + c + 1 &= 4 + 11 + 12
\end{align*}
```

gives

[image]

.

Every `\Leftrightarrow` should be centred, everything left to the equals sign should be ragged left and everything right of the equal sign should be ragged left.

The huge white space, obviously, is a problem for me. How can I solve this issue (especially if I use `align` instead of `align*`)? Using the `tabular` environment as [stated in a solution to another question that I asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460914/149141), I am afraid, will not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have `alignat`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
        &\;& a &= b\\
        \Leftrightarrow && b &= c\\
        \Leftrightarrow && c + 2 &= 3 + 5\\
        \Leftrightarrow && d + c + 1 &= 4 + 11 + 12
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You *did* say **everything right of the equal sign should be ragged left**.  I don't think you meant it, but I show it as a possibility.

Done here with TABstacks, after showing the OP's original code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
        && a &= b\\
        \Leftrightarrow&& b &= c\\
        \Leftrightarrow&& c + 2 &= 3 + 5\\
        \Leftrightarrow&& d + c + 1 &= 4 + 11 + 12
\end{align*}
\[
\setstackaligngap{6pt}% horizontal gap between align groups
\alignCenterstack{
        && a =& b\\
        \Leftrightarrow&& b =& c\\
        \Leftrightarrow&& c + 2 =& 3 + 5\\
        \Leftrightarrow&& d + c + 1 =& 4 + 11 + 12
}
\]
\[
\setstacktabbedgap{0pt}% horizontal gap between tabbed groups
\tabbedCenterstack[r]{
        & a =& b\\
        \Leftrightarrow& b =& c\\
        \Leftrightarrow& c + 2 =& 3 + 5\\
        \Leftrightarrow& d + c + 1 =& 4 + 11 + 12
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]